# Player is not responding to arduino code in Unity

Tags: unity, c#, input, single-player

So I am developing this game (as part of a larger game), where the player has to collect all the coins before moving on to the next level. I want the player to when it receives a set number of button clicks from an Arduino. Every level requires a different amount of presses. So, for example, level 1 requires 1 click, level 2 requires 2 clicks etc. The issue here is that the player isn't responding to the input and I do not know why. When I tested this code using the space key, the player moved so the issue is definitely somewhere between the player and the Arduino.  Any tips on how I can fix this issue will be very appreciated.

This is the Arduino script:

```
#include <Bounce2.h>
#include<SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Wire.h>

// Connect each button with one connection
// to GND and the other to a digital pin.
const byte buttonPin = 2;
const byte buttonPin2 = 3;

class Button{

  private:

    byte m_buttonPin;
    byte m_counter = 0;
    unsigned long m_buttonPressTimeout;
    unsigned long m_previousMillis;

  public:

    Button(byte buttonPin):
      m_buttonPin(buttonPin),
      m_counter(0),
      m_buttonPressTimeout(2000), // Button press timeout in ms.
      m_previousMillis(0){}

    void Update(){
      if(m_counter > 0 && millis() - m_previousMillis >= m_buttonPressTimeout)
      {
        //Serial.print("Count from Update() just before it's reset to 0 = ");
        Serial.println(GetCounter());
        m_counter = 0;
      }
    }

    void IncrementCounter(){
      m_counter++;
      if(m_counter > 4){m_counter = 4;}
      if(m_counter == 1)
      {
        m_previousMillis = millis();
      }
    }

    friend void IncrementCounter(Button&);

    void IncrementCounter(Button&){
      IncrementCounter();
    }

    byte GetCounter(){
      return m_counter;
    }

};

Bounce buttonOneDebouncer = Bounce();
Bounce buttonTwoDebouncer = Bounce();
Button ButtonOne(buttonPin);
Button ButtonTwo(buttonPin2);

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(buttonPin2, INPUT_PULLUP);
  buttonOneDebouncer.attach(buttonPin);
  buttonTwoDebouncer.attach(buttonPin2);
  buttonOneDebouncer.interval(25);
  buttonTwoDebouncer.interval(25);
}

void loop(){

  // Call the Update function as fast as possible.
  ButtonOne.Update();
  ButtonTwo.Update();

  // Button one pressed.
  if(buttonOneDebouncer.update()){
    if(buttonOneDebouncer.fell()){
      if(digitalRead(buttonPin2) == 0){
        ButtonOne.IncrementCounter();
      }
    }
  }

  // Button two pressed.
  if(buttonTwoDebouncer.update()){
    if(buttonTwoDebouncer.fell()){
      if(digitalRead(buttonPin) == 0){
        ButtonOne.IncrementCounter(ButtonTwo);
      }
    }
  }
  /*if(digitalRead(buttonPin) == 0 && (digitalRead(buttonPin2) == 0))
  {
  Serial.println("9");
  }*/

}
```

This is the Player script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.IO.Ports;

public class PlayerControllerb : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static int level;
    [Header("Debug")]
    [SerializeField] private PlatformProvider platformProvider;
    SerialPort sp = new SerialPort("\\\\.\\COM4", 9600);
    //player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
    private void Awake()
    {
        OnSceneLoaded();
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= OnSceneLoaded;
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneLoaded;
        print(level);
    }
    public void OnSceneLoaded()
    {

    }
    public void OnSceneLoaded(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode)
    {
        platformProvider = FindObjectOfType<PlatformProvider>();
    }
    public float Speed = 1;
    private int currentPlatformIndex;
    public Vector2 height;
    public float xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax;

    string value;
    int amount;

    void Start()
    {
        if (!sp.IsOpen)
        { // If the erial port is not open 
            sp.Open(); // Open 
        }
        sp.ReadTimeout = 1; // Timeout for reading

        print(level);
    }

    void Update()
    {

        // if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && level == 1)
        //     GoToNextPlatform();

        if (sp.IsOpen)
        { // Check to see if the serial port is open 
            try
            {

                value = sp.ReadLine(); //Read the information
                amount = int.Parse(value);
                print(amount);
                //transform.Translate(Speed * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f);  //walk

                //if (/*amount > 25f)*/Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))  //jump

                if (amount == 1 && level == 1)
                {
                    //if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
                    //{
                    GoToNextPlatform();
                    // GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(2* height, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
                }
                if (amount == 2 && level == 2)
                {
                    //if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
                    //{
                    GoToNextPlatform();
                    // GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(2* height, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
                }
                if (amount == 3 && level == 3)
                {
                    //if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
                    //{
                    GoToNextPlatform();
                    // GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(2* height, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
                }
                if (amount == 4 && level == 4)
                {
                    //if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
                    //{
                    GoToNextPlatform();
                    // GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(2* height, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {
            }
            /*GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().position = new Vector3
            (
                Mathf.Clamp(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().position.x, xMin, xMax),
                Mathf.Clamp(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().position.y, yMin, yMax)
            );*/

        }
    }
    [ContextMenu(nameof(GoToNextPlatform))]
    public void GoToNextPlatform()
    {
        currentPlatformIndex++;
        currentPlatformIndex = Mathf.Min(currentPlatformIndex, platformProvider.platforms.Length);

        GoToPlatform(currentPlatformIndex);
    }
    [ContextMenu(nameof(GoToPreviousPlatform))]
    public void GoToPreviousPlatform()
    {
        currentPlatformIndex--;
        currentPlatformIndex = Mathf.Max(currentPlatformIndex, 0);

        GoToPlatform(currentPlatformIndex);
    }
    private void GoToPlatform(int index)
    {
        //StopAllCoroutines();
        //StartCoroutine(MoveTo(platformProvider.platforms[index].transform.position));

        gameObject.transform.position = platformProvider.platforms[index].transform.position;
    }
    IEnumerator MoveRoutine(Vector3 target)
    {
        while (!Mathf.Approximately(0, Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target)))
        {
            yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().MovePosition(Vector3.MoveTowards(GetComponent<Rigidbody>().position, target, Time.deltaTime * Speed));
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().position = new Vector3

                   (
                        Mathf.Clamp(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().position.x, xMin, xMax),
                        Mathf.Clamp(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().position.y, yMin, yMax)
                    );
    }
    void ApplicationQuit()
    {
        if (sp != null)
        {

            {
                sp.Close();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This is a picture of the console to show that the inputs are being registered[image: console]. Here is an image of the game: [image: game]

Comment: I’ve only skimmed your code, but your console image seems to suggest that you receive 1 sometimes. Does `GoToNextPlatform` get called in that case? Is it working correctly?

Comment: @Ryan1729 It is working when I get 1 right now. But now, when it changes the scene, it exits play mode and gives me the error: IOException: Access is denied.

Comment: I suggest you use try/catch blocks to narrow down which line of code is causing the exception. If the problem still isn’t clear at that point, then I would add that information to the question.

Comment: @Ryan1729 Its working now; the scenes change but because the input from the Arduino isn't always accurate, the player doesn't always move

Comment: Sounds like you should edit your question to describe the problem you're solving now.